# Isolate the largest patch in a raster in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis

I have a raster with a series of patches (contiguous areas with same value). How do I isolate the largest patch? I know I could run r.stats, look through the long list of calculated areas, figure out which one is the largest and then use r.reclass to isolate it, but I'm sure there has to be an easier or more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Instead of *looking* at the `r.stats` [output](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.stats.html), why don't you just post-process it to identify the largest area? Do you perhaps have some additional requirements, such as to perform all calculations within GRASS? What kind of output do you contemplate as the result of "isolating" the largest: would that perhaps be a raster showing that largest patch or just the category of the largest patch? What do you need when there is a tie for largest?

Comment: I simply want to obtain a raster that shows the largest patch. I would preferably do it all into GRASS. I wouldn't worry about ties since the odds of two patches having the exact same number of pixels are pretty small.

Comment: OK. You might be surprised how great those odds can be, though, under certain circumstances.  For instance, if you were to classify each pixel in a largish grid (say 1,000,000 cells) randomly into two classes, there would be a 0.08% chance that the two classes would have exactly the same number of cells--small, but certainly possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run  [r.clump](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.clump.html) to recategorize the raster map pixels by grouping cells that form physically discrete areas into **unique categories**. From there, running r.report or r.stats on it, you find the "ID" (category) of the largest clump which you could extract with **r.mapcalc "newmap = if(clumpmap == NUM, 1, null()"** into a new map, as needed.

Edit: For convenience, there is now a [new](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/changeset/58399) "sort" parameter in [r.report](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.report.html) available (GRASS GIS 7). This makes it a snap to figure out the largest patch without using extra sort tools!

Edit 2: I have written up a [new example here](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Find_largest_patch_in_raster_map).

Comment: This is almost what I need. The only issue is with finding the ID of the largest clump when there are hundreds of patches.

Comment: The most straight-forward is probably to convert the clusters to area polygons (r.to.vect type=area) then add an area column to the new polygon vector and populate it (v.db.addcol and v.to.db opt=area) the select for the max area value.

Comment: I edited my answer for the new sort parameter: Martin Landa was visiting me, so we discussed the issue and he kindly implemented it for Guillaume and the rest of the world...